# RLDC Expression Editor Custom Code

Tags: c#, reportviewer, report

I'm making a .rldc report in local mode, and I'm having trouble figuring out how format my data. For one item field in a data source, the type is a class that has a unit length and a unit type. I'm wondering if it's possible in the expression editor to access each of these elements of the object I pass in. Or will I have to pass in each property of the class separately. Let me know if I need to explain anything better.

Here's the class I'm trying to access

```
public class Measurement
{
    float value;
    Unit unit;

    public float Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
    public Unit Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set { unit = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is what I have for the expression in the text box

```
<Value>=Fields!Weight.Value.Value</Value>
```

This is the report's data set's section relevant to this

```
<Field Name="Weight">
   <DataField>Weight</DataField>
   <rd:TypeName>NewCalculator.Logic.Units.Measurement</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

Thanks

Comment: When I use Local RDLC reports, I always bind default types rather than custom classes. Try translating your Unit properties into the primitives they represent.

Comment: This is my fall back plan. I was just wondering if there was a way to avoid this since I would rather not write a wrapper class for the data being passed into the report that exposes all the primitive types.

Comment: Your `Value` element is correct. Your `Field` element is also correct. Now, how about your binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no problem for the report generator to render objects with properties - you won't get intellisense support though. This does not work in version 10 of the reporting assembly.

Specify the field:

```
<Field Name="SomeClass"><DataField>SomeClass</DataField></Field>
```

Get the value (assuming your `SomeClass` has an `Id` property):

```
<Value>=Fields!SomeClass.Value.Id</Value>
```

or even

```
<Value>=Fields!SomeClass.Value.X.Y.Z.Id</Value>
```

if your class hierarchy goes like that.

### **Edit**:

Let's assume you have a class `Body`:

```
public class Body { public Measurement Weight { get; set; } ... }
```

If you bind your dataSource like this:

```
ReportDataSource rdsBodies = new ReportDataSource("Bodies",
  new Body[] { new Body(), new Body() });
localReport.DataSources.Add(rdsBodies);
```

and specify your `<DataSet>` like this:

```
<DataSet Name="Bodies">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="Weight"><DataField>Weight</DataField></Field>
  </Fields>
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>Bodies</CommandText>
  </Query>
</DataSet>
```

the value

```
<Value>=Fields!Weight.Value.Value</Value>
```

should render without errors if it is inside a `List` or `Table` with

```
<DataSetName>Bodies</DataSetName>
```

Comment: I did what you said, but the field just shows #Error. I'll edit my post to show exactly what my code and report looks like.

Comment: @wangburger: what's important is the binding you use in your `ReportDataSource`, `<DataSet><Fields><Field>` definitions and your class hierarchy. RDL can only render simple types so if you try to render `=Fields!SomeClass.Value.X` that is some class instance, it will usually end-up as **#Error**.

Comment: I posted what the field definition looks like for what I'm trying to bind. Measurement.Value is just a float, so I don't think it should be having trouble displaying it.

Comment: @wangburger: checkout my updated answer. I have even tried it on my report generator and it works. Also make sure the bound object is **strongly** typed (eg.: NOT an array of objects).

Comment: I'm not having any luck figuring this out in my project. I have everything like you do. I'm gonna try to reproduce this error from a scratch project. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The only other things I can think that are worth metioning are that I'm binding to ObservableCollection<Part> and that Part.Weight is an abstract property. But I don't think either of those should matter since I'm displaying another abstract primitive property just fine, and I added the observable collection to an array and bound that.

Comment: @wangburger: Are you using the **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms 9.0.0.0** assembly for the `LocalReport`?

Comment: @wangburger: And that is your answer. If you "downgrade" to v9.0.0.0 it will work. I found the v9 version more compliant and also faster.